# Is COUNT faster than pulling the records and counting in code?

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the situation:

1. I first need to run a query to know how many records exist.

   For example: `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) from users;`
2. Often this will be all that's needed.  However, sometimes (say 30% of the time) following the first query, the user will want to run a second query, detailing the records.

   For example: `SELECT * FROM users;`

Is there any reason to run `SELECT COUNT` initially instead of just `SELECT`?  That is, is making the count of records in SQL faster than actually pulling the records back?  Or is it doing essentially the same work either way and so I should avoid doing two queries?

In other words, is it better to just always pull the records in the first query (not use `COUNT`), then count the records in code (Java).  If the user wants to run the second query, then great, I already have the data.  If not, then just dump it.

What's the best practice here?

Comment: It's much faster to run the count in SQL. Apart from anything else, you don't need to send the entire table over the wire, just one integer value!

Comment: @Blorgbeard Right, I understand using COUNT will mean much less data needs to be transferred, but how much of the overall cost of doing the query is that transfer vs what the SQL server is doing?  (I know that will depend on many factors.  Just wondering what the best practice is.)

Comment: 1) Yes.  2) Try it yourself and see.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

If you know you need the data, go ahead and pull it and count it in code.  However, if you only need the count, it is significantly faster to pull the count from the database than it is to actually retrieve rows.  Also it is standard practice to only pull what you need.

For instance, if you are counting all the rows in a table, most database implementations do not need to look at any rows.  Tables know how many rows they have. If the query has filters in the `where` clause and it can use an index, it again will not need to look at the actual rows' data, just counts the rows from the index.

And all this is not counting the less data transferred.

A rule of thumb about database speeds is go ahead and try it for yourself. General rules are not always a good indicator.  For instance, if the table was 10 rows and only a few columns, I might just pull the whole thing anyway on the off chance I needed it, since 2 round trips to the database would outweigh the cost of the query.

Answer (score 4):

Two things should be considered

## QUERY #1

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT userid) from users;
```

This query will go a whole lot faster with an index on `userid`; If you do not have an index on `userid` and none of the indexes you already have begin with `userid`, then run this:

```
ALTER TABLE user ADD INDEX (userid);
```

This will make the Query Optimizer choose to look through the index rather than touch the table.

## QUERY #2

```
SELECT * from users;
```

Why bother to fetch every column in each row just to count the row?

You can replace that with

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM users;
```

where id is the PRIMARY KEY or

```
SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users;
```

You will have to benchmark which query is faster, `SELECT COUNT(id)` or `SELECT COUNT(1)`

## EPILOGUE

Unless you actually need the data while counting, let the counting happen in the server.

Answer (score 2):

It's faster because:

- Database is designed and written in a way to make things like that as fast as possible.
- You don't have to send entire table into your application. Just one integer instead.

**You should never send whole table and count application side!**

Comment: I disagree with "never", one might have a simple table used for configuration and stuff like that, with just a few dozen lines, reading the full table is perfectly fine in cases like that.

Answer (score 0):

Just a personal opinion:

If your "detailed" query is not needed on 100% of the cases, then it makes sense to use the `count()` function of MySQL. It is faster and cheaper: MySQL does the 'heavy' count task and sends a tiny chunk of data, instead of sending a huge chunk of data and leave your app the 'heavy' task of traversing the recordset and counting the rows.

That said, the usual tip: Make sure your tables are properly indexed, so your queries run optimally.