# How to get the number of rows in a database table with Flutter SQFlite

Tags: dart, flutter, sqflite

How do I get the row count of a database table in Flutter. I am using the SQFlite plugin.

I assume that it is similar to Android, but Android has `DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, TABLE_NAME)`. Does SQFlite have something similar?

I am answering the question to the best of my knowledge below, but I would be glad for a better answer if there is one.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can use

```
int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_name'));
```

where `db` is an [SQFlite](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/sqflite) `Database`.

**Source:** I found this [here](https://grokonez.com/flutter/flutter-sqlite-example-crud-sqflite-example) and in the [source code](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/lib/sqflite.dart#L79).

Comment: and this is an alternative without raw: `Future<int> getCount() async => firstIntValue(await (await db).query(tableName, columns: ['COUNT(*)'])) ?? 0;`

Answer (score 16):

**Try this function:**

```
Future<int> getCount() async {
    //database connection
    Database db = await this.database;
    var x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT (*) from 
    $Table');
    int count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No more hard function invocations needed. just try with `.length`
If you are using a data model you can use its' name at `MODEL_NAME`.

```
Future<int> getCount() async {

Database db = await this.database;
var result = await db.query(MODEL_NAME.TABLE_NAME);
int count = result.length;
return count;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [magic column COUNT(*) as shown in the docs](https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/sql.md#sqlite-schema-information)

Hence, the count function would look something like:

```
  @override
  Future<int> countUsersWithFirstName(String firstName) async {
    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(await db.query(
          'users',
          columns: ['COUNT(*)'],
          where: 'firstName = ?',
          whereArgs: [firstName],
        )) ??
        0;
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe a **better way** to do this is inside the DatabaseHelper/Service `class`:

```
class DbService {
  static Database _db; //static = only a single copy of _db is shared among all the instances of this class (Database)
  static int _count;

  static int get count => _count;
  ...
```

this way every time a `query` gets executed the `count` updates, this also makes it possible to update the `count` on queries with filters without having to write a new `function` for it :

```
  List<Map> result = await db.query('myDatabase');
  _count = result.length;
  return result;
}
```

and then simply use `DbService.count` to get the count

Comment: A "better way" would be to retrieve ALL records then get the length? Am I missing something?

Comment: "Better way", will be to use raw count query. Count is much more faster as there minimal to no retrieval of data. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15912749/is-count-faster-than-pulling-the-records-and-counting-in-code

Answer (score 0):

You can also use

```
List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM table_name');
int count = list.length;
```

Comment: It is not recommended to load all records in list just to check count of records. Always use `count(*)` function.

Comment: Your function will slow down your app, because it will load all records data and it take a lot of time to execute rather than use count

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
class DatabaseHelper() {

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getDataInMap() async {
      Database database = await this.database;
      return database.query("ahkam_fiqhia");
  }

  Future<List<BooksModel>> getModelsFromMapList() async {
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> mapList = await getDataInMap();

    List<DataModel> dataModel = List();

    for (int i = 0; i < mapList.length; i++) {
      dataModel(DataModel(mapList[i]));
    }
    print(mapList.length);
    return dataModel;
  }

}
```

Add `initState()` function in your view then call `getModelsFromMapList` function:

```
class _MainView extends State<MainView> {

  DatabaseHelper dbHelper = databaseHelper();  

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    databaseHelper.getModelsFromMapList();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my code using for custom column condition count

```
Future<int?> getCustomTaskCount(String t1) async {
Database? _database = await database;
if (_database != null) {
  var result = Sqflite.firstIntValue(await _database.rawQuery(
      'SELECT COUNT (*) FROM tableName WHERE columnName=?',
      [t1]));
  print(result);
  return result;
}}
```