# How to get returned data and rows length from using database methods to another classes in flutter

Tags: flutter

I cannot get returned data and length of rows in database, how to solve this problem? And the codes are the following.

**In test_type_model.dart**

```
class TestTypeModel {
  int? id;
  String? testTitle;

  TESTTypeModel({
   this.id,
   this.testTitle,
});

  TestTypeModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id: json['id'];
    testTitle: json['test_title'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': this.id,
      'testTitle': this.testTitle
    };
  }
}
```

**In databaseHeplder.dart**

```
class DataBaseHelper {
  late Database database;
  Future<TestTypeModel> getTotalTitle() async {

    final db = await database;

    final maps = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(id) FROM test_type');

    print('map: ' + maps[0].toString());

    return TestTypeModel.fromJson(maps[0]);
  }
}
```

In `print()` can show `'map: {COUNT(id): 29}'` it is correct in printing but I need the `length` for `ListView.builder` in `itemCount` the `length` of this data.
Finally I can't get its returned data and its length.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
final result = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(1) FROM test_type');
final count = Sqflite.firstIntValue(result);
```

[Answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54097848/9922576)
[Here is an example](https://pub.dev/packages/sqflite)